# how is this program working [python 3.x]?

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning python 3.x and got stuck on this program. Can someone please explain me whats happening in this program?

input:-

```
   pairs = [(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (4, 'four')]
   pairs.sort(key=lambda pair: pair[1])
```

output:-

```
   [(4, 'four'), (1, 'one'), (3, 'three'), (2, 'two')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`key=lambda pair: pair[1]` is used to compare elements in the list during sorting. Since the lambda indexes a pair to its second value, it will compare the strings 'one', 'two', etc during sorting.

Strings are compared by their [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) which is similar to alphabetical order, but also defines orderings for non alphabet characters too (like punctuation and digits). Sorting by the strings results in the pair with 'four' being first since it starts with 'f' and 'one' being second since it starts with 'o' and `'f' < 'o'` etc.

Comment: what kind of comparison?

Comment: @k4droid3 Not sure what your asking, but sort uses less than `<`.

Comment: let it be I got the answer :D

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting the pairs by the second variable ([1]) which are : 'one','two','three','four' therefore they will be sorted by their alphabetical value.